# Could not launch application by calling a URL from Android Browser

Tags: android, url, browser, android-intent

There are many answers in stackoverflow showing how to lauch app from a web browser ,but I am not sure what went wrong with my code, that never seems to be doing the intended.
I am trying to launch my app by a URL from any other app like web browser,initially 
my manifest file looks like this

```
      <activity android:name=".Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
              <data android:scheme="http" android:host="ebay.com" />
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And When I typed http://ebay.com in the browser that never started my app.Obviously,how does the browser know about my app?,then i tried the other way around and added another Activity called MyActivity and altered the manifest file as

```
<activity android:name=".Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>     

 <activity android:name=".MyActivity">
      <intent-filter>
         <data android:scheme="http"  android:host="ebay.com" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

and tried in my Main Activity 
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://mycityway.com")));

Thus producing the intended result.I can also start another application Activity using this method.

But most of the answers here says that the later is possible.What is the mistake i am doing,I couldn't launch my app from browser.Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And When I typed http://ebay.com in the browser that never started my
>   app.

It gets started when a matching link is clicked not when you type the url in the browser.
Try it by sending yourself an email containing http://ebay.com and click the link in the email application.